# subtract two columns then add some value and insert in third column using trigger in oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, calculated-columns

i am using oracle 10 g i have been told to do this task using trigger i have come up with this

```
|`create trigger total
on inventory
after insert or update
for each row 
begin set 
:new.total=:new.stockin - :new.stockout +20;
end;`|
```

error missing before,after 
i want total = stockin -stockout + 20

table inventory

```
|stcokin |               |stockout |                | total|
 |-------|               |---------|                |------|
|2|                        |5|                         | 23|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You should assign using :=
- You should edit the new values before updating or inserting. After update is ment to (for example) update other tables
- I think your trigger name was causing problems too.

so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_total BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON inventory
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.total := :NEW.stockin - :NEW.stockout + 20;
END;
```

Comment: still getting error ora-04071:missing before,after or instead of keyword

Comment: @PaariThirugnanasambandam then you should mark the reply as correct :-)